# Kubernetes getting started locally with docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

I am attempting to setup Kubernetes locally using a docker instance. I am following [this documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/) but get stuck at the point of creating a new service and exposing the ports.

I have the docker container pulled and I have a `kubectl` available.

When I run the command `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` I get the following

```
|NAME       | STATUS  |  AGE   |    LABELS                            |
|-----------|---------|--------|--------------------------------------|
|127.0.0.1  | Ready   |  1h    |    kubernetes.io/hostname=127.0.0.1  |
```

I now create a new service with `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80` as per the docs. When I run `docker ps` I see a container that's been created using my local nginx:latest image.

```
CONTAINER_ID: 4192d1b423ec        
IMAGE: nginx
COMMAND: "nginx -g 'daemon off'"
CREATED: 37 minutes ago
STATUS: Up 37 minutes                           
NAMES: k8s_nginx.aab52821_nginx-198147104-qop91_default_f1cf5d8a-ef2d-11e5-b527-f0def1de109f_940ee216
```

The next step is where I'm having problems `kubectl expose rc nginx --port=80` is supposed to expose the nginx image as a kubernetes service on port 80.

I get this in the terminal.

> **Error** from server: replicationcontrollers "nginx" not found

So I started reading about replicationcontrollers, I understand the concepts but I do not know how they are configured or setup. This got me to thinking that I'm following what should be an idiot proof setup guide. Can anyone help me with this? I have added my docker and kubernetes versions below.

## Version info

#### Docker version (Local Ubuntu 15.10)

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:59:07 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:59:07 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

#### Kubernetes version

```
Client Version: version.Info{
    Major:"1", 
    Minor:"2", 
    GitVersion:"v1.2.0",
    GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3",
    GitTreeState:"clean"
}

Server Version: version.Info{
    Major:"1",
    Minor:"2",
    GitVersion:"v1.2.0",
    GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3",
    GitTreeState:"clean"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes documentation for docker is outdated for now. Some elements need to be added.

This [kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869) is the one to follow.

You can find at [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869#issuecomment-194149162) the answer to setup. It's working for me with DNS/Dashboard addons. I have not done a complete test of all the features but complexe application are running on it (understand not helloworld application).

If you are interested, you can find some project that try to solve this setup that is not so trivial if you don't have time:

- [hive](https://github.com/tdeheurles/hive)
- [kmachine](https://github.com/skippbox/kmachine)

Note I don't put any setup here as it will certainly be outdated soon ... Kubernetes documentation is the good place (and for now the issue I pointed you to ^^)

Comment: That GH issue is very helpful, I think I understand it now. I did a quick inspect on the kublet container and realised the mounts were not working. I've modified the mount points in line with that GH issue. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks for this.

Comment: I got it all up and running with the help from that issue and have started building out my services successfully. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidBarker could you please share what solution you applied? I'm also getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: @Viki this was a long time ago but I believe the comment linked solved the issue for me back then. Today mind you I would probably create a kubernetes deployment definition that exposed the right port and apply that with `kubectl apply -f <filename>`

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did the same, and its resolved now. Just for info, I created deployment as follow:

`$ kubectl create deployment kubia --image=luksa/kubia`

`$ kubectl expose deployment kubia --type=LoadBalancer --port 8080`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `Kubernetes` on top of `Docker` have a look at [Kubernetes Anywhere](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes-anywhere/#feature-summary). They say:

> All you need is one or more Docker hosts.